# Flash toggle snapping

Tags: flash

long, long ago in a galaxy far far away,  You used to be able to toggle snapping in Flash with the ctrl key.  Let's say you were dragging the end of a line very close to another object.  You could very easily hold the ctrl key down to shut off the snapping and get it in there nice and close without the snap.  At some point, Macromedia removed this functionality.

I'm wondering if that single-key-toggle-snapping functionality has gone somewhere else within the app or do I have to click through the menus every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is, I've scoured the docs and could not find anything about it. 
The weird thing is also that you can't set a keyboard shortcut for toggling it. The option is there, but it's grayed out for some reason. The best I could manage was setting a shortcut for the object-snapping (since that's what i use the most) and just toggling that.

Also, you don't need to go through the menus, the magnet button on the toolbar toggles snapping too.

Comment: thanks.. I suspected so.. From an illustrators point of view, it was key in drawing precisely with Flash.